# I have cURL installed on Ubuntu 14 with PHP 7 but getting still Call to undefined function curl_init()

Tags: ubuntu, curl, php-7

when i run below command :

```
 locate curl.so
```

Than below is the out put.

```
/usr/lib/php/20151012/curl.so
/usr/lib/php/20170718/curl.so
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycurl.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0
```

and after that i execute the below cmd. `locate curl.ini`

output as below.

```
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-curl.ini
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-curl.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/curl.ini
/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/curl.ini
/usr/share/php7.0-curl/curl/curl.ini
/usr/share/php7.2-curl/curl/curl.ini
/var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:php:7.0:mods-available:curl.ini
/var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:php:7.2:mods-available:curl.ini
```

every thing seems good(curl already installed) but still getting error.
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init().

Updated output for

[image]

Comment: sudo apt-get install php-curl

Comment: your curl installation is malfunctioning for some reason. run `<?php phpinfo(~0);`, what do you get?

Comment: @hanshenrik: I have executed your code. but it returns large data so i have pick module part of that. updated image in edited question

Comment: @vijaybirsingh it list the curl module author regardless of curl being installed or not. see the curl section here, http://ratma.net/phpinfo.php , it looks like this https://i.imgur.com/XEr7xci.png  , do you have such a curl section in your phpinfo() ?

Comment: @hanshenrik:I don't have any section like this.

Comment: @vijaybirsingh then the curl module isn't properly installed. what does your phpinfo() say about "Configuration File (php.ini) Path", "Loaded Configuration File", and "Additional .ini files parsed" ?

Comment: @hanshenrik; here is my phpinfo(). [phpinfo](http://35.154.250.188/vtiger/) Please let me know what can i do in my case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170023/discussion-between-hanshenrik-and-vijaybir-singh).